# Question about Solve

Tags: equation-solving

I don't understand what *Mathematica* is doing to get these solutions. 
I ask it to solve two equations, the left hand side of both expressions are the same, the right hand sides differ by a ± sign. I really don't think the solutions should be the same, but that is what *Mathematica* returns, without any comment.

```
FullSimplify[{
  Solve[1/2 E^(-((2 I l π)/k)) (-(-1 + E^(I ((4 l π)/k + δ))) Sqrt[ρ] + Sqrt[-2 E^(I ((4 l π)/k + δ)) (-2 + ρ) + ρ + E^(2 I ((4 l π)/k + δ)) ρ]) == E^(2 π I m/n), ρ], 
  Solve[1/2 E^(-((2 I l π)/k)) (-(-1 + E^(I ((4 l π)/k + δ))) Sqrt[ρ] + Sqrt[-2 E^(I ((4 l π)/k + δ)) (-2 + ρ) + ρ + E^(2 I ((4 l π)/k + δ)) ρ]) == -E^(2 π I m/n), ρ]
}]
```

*Mathematica* returns

> ```
> {
>   {{ρ -> (-1 + Cos[(4 m π)/n - δ])/(-1 + Cos[(4 l π)/k + δ])}}, 
>   {{ρ -> (-1 + Cos[(4 m π)/n - δ])/(-1 + Cos[(4 l π)/k + δ])}}
> }
> ```

Can anyone can shed some light on this, please?

Comment: Check for branch cuts ...

Comment: Yes, that would explain it.